# Java Application Build

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, build

We have a Java EE application which requires **some jar files**, a **JVM** and **Tomcat**.

How do I create a build through which a user can install and run my application in a non Java Windows environment?

The user won't need to install a JVM or Tomcat separately, but my build will configure a JVM and Tomcat for my application.

Comment: are you making a web app? if yes then why would you require user to install jvm or tomcat if he/she can directly access your application using a browser?

Comment: we are making a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

The Java installer creates a couple of registry entries but these are not necessary for it to run. So what you can do:

1. Ask for permission to package Java along with your code (the Java VM *is* copyrighted work, so you can't simply do what you want)
2. Install Java once and then simply add the new files on the hard disk to your installer
3. Unpack Tomcat and add those files as well
4. Copy your app into the tomcat/webapp/ folder
5. Write a script that packages and configures everything